# bind event to dynamically created iframe element

Tags: jquery, dom, iframe

I want to bind an event listener to an element that is not yet existing in the DOM. Now this would be a case for jQuery.on().

But in this very case, I have to bind the event to an element in an iFrame. That could be managed by

```
$("#iFrame").contents().find(".my_element").bind(...
```

et cetera. But I am in the situation, that the element is NOT yet present in the iFrame-Document (its added by user interaction), thus .find() would return an empty array and the event wouldn't be binded.

Is it even possible to bind event listeners to iFrame-specific elements that are created later? I only find solutions for already existing elements, sporting contents() and find().

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would assign event change or ready to iframe and in callback I would try to assign just like you wrote.

Comment: so you wanna bind an event to an element that does not yet exist? why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#iframe").load(function(){
    $("#iFrame").contents().find(".my_element").bind('click',function(){
       // Your code here
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.. Cheers..

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe my problem properly. The element is created via another user input, so it will never be present in the DOM automatically. So 'find' will always return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution which works well. If this does not work, just check if the iframe exists via `alert( $("#iframe").length );`. Value must be higher then 0.

```
$("#iframe").contents().find('body').on("click", ".my_element", function (e)
{
    alert("Give it to me dude ;)");
});
```